# How to prevent text move to the left after removing left border?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am making a navigation menu including some menu items. Ideally, when user selects one item, I want a orange border shown on the left of the menu item. My code is here:

```
<menu>
  <div style="margin-left: -12px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <menu_item ng-class="<<show orange border css class:updateBorderItem>>"> </menu-item>
    <menu_item >
        <a ng-click="panel.selectItem(1)" ng-class="'menu_item'" ng-href="www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
    </menu_item>
</div>

... Other items.
```

Basically, there are 2 menu items inside one "div" represeting one menu item. the first item is only shown when user clicks on this menu item 1.

The problem is that the wording is moving to a little bit to right when user clicks on it and to a little bit to left when user selects other menu item.

Before:

```
 Go To Google
```

After:

```
 | Go To Google
```

Select another item:

```
 Go To Google
```

I want the wording not moving at all. How can I do it ?

```
  My css:

.updateBorderItem {
    border-left: 3px solid orange;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a transparent value for your default menu item like:

```
menu > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
menu > div > menu_item {
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
menu > div > menu_item:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid orange;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b22czx97/)

**EDIT**

OnClick event jQuery to change the selected menu_item: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b22czx97/1/)

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you, it's most like the same solution as @emmanuel. check working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b22czx97/)

Comment: how to integrate jquery code into my angularjs contoller ?

Comment: Or you can use like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b22czx97/4/), anyway, all depends on how your using your structure.